# Can I use JSON to format column height and width in a list with hyperlinks?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am using JSON to format the height and width of my columns in a SharePoint list.

Some of these columns are set to be hyperlinks or advanced rich text. When I apply the JSON formatting, it takes the hyperlinks out and makes them the full URL. Is there any way to fix this? Here is the JSON I am using for the height and width:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "min-height": "1em",
    "height": "11em",
    "width": "300px"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For hyperlink columns, you can use JSON like below to keep the hyperlink URL and description as is in default SharePoint list view:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "min-height": "1em",
    "height": "11em",
    "width": "300px"
  }
}
```

You can apply other styling like color, background color, etc. as per your requirements.

**List view - before formatting**:

[image]

**List view - after formatting**:

[image]